# update on different type node

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

I am trying to draw body node type and also polygonesprite.  when i am going to update both type on update method.  i got issues.

This is polygone type:

```
BombBallSprite *bomb = BombBallSprite::spriteWithWorld(world);
bomb->getBody()->SetType(b2_staticBody);
bomb->activateCollisions();

this->addChild(bomb);
```

This is body node type:

```
 this->addBodyNode(node, 0);
 node->release();
```

This above two types are drawing in single scene.

When i update on both, i have issues:

```
 void HelloWorld::update(float dt)
 {
     if( gameState_ != kGameStatePaused )
     {
        world_->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
     }

     this->checkAndSliceObjects();

}


void HelloWorld::checkAndSliceObjects()
{
double curTime = getTimeTick();

for (b2Body* b = world_->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
{
    if (b->GetUserData() != NULL)
    {

        PolygonSprite *sprite = (PolygonSprite*)b->GetUserData();
        BodyNode *node = (BodyNode*) b->GetUserData();
        if( node && (node->properties_ & BN_PROPERTY_SPRITE_UPDATED_BY_PHYSICS) ) {

          -------

        }

        if (sprite->getSliceEntered() && curTime > sprite->getSliceEntryTime())
        {
            sprite->setSliceEntered(false);
        }
        else if (sprite->getSliceEntered() && sprite->getSliceExited())
        {
            this->splitPolygonSprite(sprite); 
        }                      
    }

}
```

}

I am clueless how will handle the followings on update method

```
    PolygonSprite *sprite = (PolygonSprite*)b->GetUserData();
    BodyNode *node = (BodyNode*) b->GetUserData();
```

Can any one assist me?

Comment: please explain what these "issues" are

Comment: It goes to the thread "b2Fixture::GetBody()" ("Thread 1: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1, address=0xc008476f)"

Comment: Then another time:  it shows in Thread1: "0 type info name for polygoneSprite"

Comment: Third issue in the place: b2Assert(3 <= count && count <= b2_maxPolygonVertices);  (i am using box2d 2.2.0 version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one short cut method.

You have to set tag for all.   E.g. polygone sprite for 100, sprite for 200.

It is possible to check tag using user data.  If the tag is 100, you will do polygone sprite update.  If the tag is 200, you will do sprite update.

I think it will help you.